# combine multiple rows result in single row based on one column value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, grouping

I i want to combine multiple rows result into single row based on one column called type.

Ex say suppose i have below result from my query .

```
seqnum  type    name
456     SH    Google2
456     CN    transwork
123     SH    partyshipper
123     CN    consignee
```

Actual result i want is something like below table

```
seqnum  consigneename    shippername
456     transwork         Google2
123     consignee         partyshipper
```

Basically i want to get result like consignee name  when type is CN and shipper name is when type is SH if its not both then i can add extra column with name just like otherparty.
I can get result and iterate result set and set value of object. but i think this will be better if we get formatted result in query only.can some one help in in getting this.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this usually helps; lines #1 - 7 represent your sample data. Code you need begins at line #8.

```
SQL> with test (seqnum, type, name) as
  2    (select 456, 'SH', 'Google2'      from dual union all
  3     select 456, 'CN', 'transwork'    from dual union all
  4     select 123, 'SH', 'partyshipper' from dual union all
  5     select 123, 'CN', 'consignee'    from dual union all
  6     select 999, 'XX', 'littlefoot'   from dual
  7    )
  8  select seqnum,
  9    max(case when type = 'CN' then name end) consigneename,
 10    max(case when type = 'SH' then name end) shipppername,
 11    max(case when type not in ('CN', 'SH') then name end) otherparty
 12  from test
 13  group by seqnum;

    SEQNUM CONSIGNEENAM SHIPPPERNAME OTHERPARTY
---------- ------------ ------------ ------------
       123 consignee    partyshipper
       999                           littlefoot
       456 transwork    Google2

SQL>
```

Comment: @Hema: You are supposed to **accept** the answer that serves you best. (I.e. click the check/tick next to the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing the query from @Littlefoot. You may also use PIVOT for this getting the expected result.

```
    with test (seqnum, type, name) as
      (select 456, 'SH', 'Google2'      from dual union all
       select 456, 'CN', 'transwork'    from dual union all
       select 123, 'SH', 'partyshipper' from dual union all
       select 123, 'CN', 'consignee'    from dual union all
       select 999, 'OT', 'littlefoot'   from dual
      )
select * from test
pivot (
  min(name) for type in 
      (        
        'SH' shippingname
      , 'CN' consigneename 
      , 'OT' someother
      )
)
;


    SEQNUM SHIPPINGNAME CONSIGNEENAM SOMEOTHER   
---------- ------------ ------------ ------------
       999                           littlefoot  
       456 Google2      transwork                
       123 partyshipper consignee
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd self join the table and filter different `type`s in each side of the join:

```sql
SELECT          COALESCE(c.seqnum, s.seqnum) AS seqnum,
                COALESCE(c.name, 'other') AS consigneename,
                COALESCE(s.name, 'other') AS shippername
FROM            (SELECT * 
                 FROM   mytable
                 WHERE  type = 'CN') c
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
                 FROM   mytable
                 WHERE  type = 'SN') s ON c.seqnum = s.seqnum
```

Comment: I suppose that the `WHERE` clause renders the join a mere inner join. (And with full outer joins I prefer `USING` over `ON` so as to reduce `COALESCE(c.seqnum, s.seqnum) AS seqnum` to `seqnum` :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner good catch, thanks. I was trying to lazy-out of using subqueries, but clearly that was just wrong, as you pointed out.